# Postgresql Numeric type display in python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a postgresql table with column defined as: `numeric(20,7)`
If I insert the value `0` it saves it as: `0.0000000`

When I assign this value to Python (2.7) it shows me `0E-7` which is correct but a wrong format.

Why does it shows it like this? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format a [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) simply by passing it to:

```
"{:f}".format(Decimal("0E-7"))
```

The `Decimal` supports [advanced string formatting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/):

```
# PEP 3101 support.  the _localeconv keyword argument should be
# considered private: it's provided for ease of testing only.
def __format__(self, specifier, context=None, _localeconv=None):
    """Format a Decimal instance according to the given specifier.

    The specifier should be a standard format specifier, with the
    form described in PEP 3101.  Formatting types 'e', 'E', 'f',
    'F', 'g', 'G', 'n' and '%' are supported.  If the formatting
    type is omitted it defaults to 'g' or 'G', depending on the
    value of context.capitals.
    """
```

By default it seems to use the precision of the `Decimal` itself:

```
>>> '{:f}'.format(Decimal('0E-7'))
'0.0000000'
>>> '{:f}'.format(Decimal('0E-8'))
'0.00000000'
>>> '{:f}'.format(Decimal('0E-9'))
'0.000000000'
```

If on the other hand you want to use a custom precision, pass it in the format string:

```
>>> print("{:.2f}".format(Decimal("0E-7")))
0.00
```

For an explanation on what the different letters in the format mean, consult the ["Format Specification Mini-Language"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to control the way a float number is formatted, you could try:

```
"{0:.2f}".format(n) # n is value read from db
```

Comment: Can you explain the syntax? why .2?

Comment: @java `.<precision>f` sets the precision of the float. I think pablo chose 2 points arbitrarily.